# Adding Option Group to Query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add an Option Group to this select box.  I am getting the rows and the count of the number of options in the record set.  I can either get the count or set the group.  I have yet to do both!

```
<select name="DETAILS">
<?php
include("config.php");
$sql = "SELECT tblDetails.DetailType AS type, CONCAT(tblDetails.DetailName,' (', Count(tblLocDet.DetailID),')') AS DetailName
FROM tblLocations INNER JOIN (tblLocDet INNER JOIN tblDetails ON tblLocDet.DetailID = tblDetails.DetailID) ON tblLocations.LocationID = tblLocDet.LocationID
GROUP BY tblDetails.DetailType, tblDetails.DetailName, tblLocations.CityID, tblLocations.AreaID, tblLocations.CuisineID
HAVING (((tblLocations.CityID)=16) AND ((tblLocations.AreaID)=131) AND ((tblLocations.CuisineID)=3));";


$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());  

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
   echo "<optgroup label='{$row['type']}'>"; 
   $DetailNames = explode('|', $row['DetailName']); 
   foreach($DetailNames as $DetailName) { 
      echo "<option value='".$DetailName."'>".$DetailName."</option>"; 
   } 
   echo "</optgroup>"; 
}  
?>
</select>
```

Help is appreciated.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: What do you mean you can get the count set or the group but not both? What count? What group? Is it the query you're having difficulty with or the PHP output?

Comment: I'm trying to build an option group in the select box.  I successfuly built the group, (Code not shown) however I needed a count of each option in the group that pretains to the current recordset.  Thats when the trouble began.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning `mysql_query` will be removed in future versions of PHP so this code will stop working entirely.